# Start Windows Service in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to start a windows service that was just installed.

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
if (bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunService"]))
{
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new IvrService() };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

The IvrService code is:

```
partial class IvrService : ServiceBase
{
    public IvrService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Process myProcess;
        myProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        string pathname = Path.GetDirectoryName(myProcess.MainModule.FileName);

        //eventLog1.WriteEntry(pathname);

        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathname);

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        string sProcessName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            if (sProcessName.ToLower() != "services.exe")
            {
                // In an interactive session.
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new IvrInteractive());
                IvrApplication.Start(); // the key function of the service, start it here
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to start the service. Using `ServiceController.Start()?` But I already have `ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);` Is it for starting a service?

Code hint is definitely appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an `appSetting` with the key `RunService` and the value `true`?

Comment: Yes, I have it. It is set as true already.

Comment: So what happens when you hit F5?

Comment: It gave me a warning, Windows Service Start Failure. Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A windows Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServiceExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NETSTART command. But I saw the service is indeed in services management panel.

Comment: Are you trying to run it in Visual Studio?  Windows Services can't be run directly in Visual Studio, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I run it in VS 2012. I have to debug it.Do I need call OnStart()? I saw there is an example at http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/. How can I apply it to my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question about starting a service from code, you would want something like this (which would be equivalent to running `net start myservice` from the command line):

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "myservice";

if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running || 
    sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Service is already running");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Start pending... ");
        sc.Start();
        sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));

        if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service started successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service not started.");
            Console.WriteLine("  Current State: {0}", sc.Status.ToString("f"));
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not start the service.");
    }
}
```

This will start the service, but keep in mind that it will be a different process than the one that is executing the above code.

Now to answer the question about debugging a service.

- One option is to attach *after* the service has been started.
- The other is to make your service executable be able to run the main code, not as a service but as a normal executable (typically setup via a command line parameter). Then you can F5 into it from your IDE.

EDIT: Adding sample flow of events (based on questions from some of the comments)

1. OS is asked to start a service. This can be done from the control panel, the command line, APIs (such as the code above), or automatically by the OS (depending on the service's startup settings).
2. The operating system then creates a new process.
3. The process then registers the service callbacks (for example `ServiceBase.Run` in C# or `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` in native code). And then starts running its code (which will call your `ServiceBase.OnStart()` method).
4. The OS can then request that a service be paused, stopped, etc. At which point it will send a control event to the already running process (from step 2). Which will result in a call to your `ServiceBase.OnStop()` method.

EDIT: Allowing a service to run as a normal executable or as a command line app: One approach is to configure your app as a console application, then run different code based on a command line switch:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        // we are running as a service
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
    else if (args[0].Equals("/debug", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // run the code inline without it being a service
        MyService debug = new MyService();
        // use the debug object here
    }
```

Comment: Is this same as ServiceBase.OnStart Method()?

Comment: @Love - no, `ServiceBase.OnStart()` is called automatically by the operating system when it is asked to start your service (after first creating a new process).

Comment: So how about ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); Do I have to remove it from my code and replace it with yours? How to make your service executable be able to run the main code? Please correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the service using InstallUtil, e.g.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe C:\MyService.exe
```

You need to start the service from the command line, e.g.

```
net start ServiceName // whatever the service is called
```

Then you need to attach to the process with Visual Studio, via Tools > Attach To Process.

Stick the breakpoints in the solution wherever you want it to break and the dev environment should take over.

To start it from the dev environment, put the `net start ServiceName` command into a batch file, and then in the Project Properties > Build Events "Post Build Event Command Line" you can add the path to the batch file.

*note that looking now, I'm not sure if you need to even use a batch file, you might be able to put the command directly in there. Try and edit this answer with whatever works.

Comment: I already installed it via code. I want to start it from code instead of command line. I am designing a service controller, which is a console application.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a suggestion. If this isn't what you're looking for, I'm out of suggestions!!

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I am looking for. I guess that My code has flaw. I didn't call OnStart(), thus although I installed the service but it is empty and doing nothing.

Comment: An alternative is using the "sc" windows service controller utility. Its able to control and in/uninstall services. No more installutil/net start =)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static bool StartWindowsService(string serviceName)
    {
        bool isStarted = false;
        try
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            service.Start();
            var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); // 5seconds
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            isStarted = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            return isStarted;
        }
        return isStarted;
    }
```