# windows service not executing OnStart entry point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I have a windows service installed,

```
Some.WindowsService wService = new WindowsService();
Some.Server server = new Server();
Some.Service service = new Service();
Some.Request request = new Some.Request(msg, Id);
var ReturnedResult = server.Execute(request);
```

I checked in Service, the "Some" is running in Service normally.
I don't know how to initialize so that I can reach the protected `OnStart()` function in WindowsService, and so that it can call the functions in `OnStart()` Function.

Any idea are appreciated. Thanks a lot. : )

Comment: Are you trying to debug your service? Or is it not executing your OnStart entry point? See if this thread helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140045/start-windows-service-in-c-sharp/19141127#19141127

Answer (score 1):

One way you can test this is write a log file or the [windows event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42ste2f3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog appLog = 
    new System.Diagnostics.EventLog() ;
appLog.Source = "This Application's Name";
appLog.WriteEntry("An entry to the Application event log.");
```